# show the selected value from dropdownlist bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I´m designing a form using bootstrap and jQuery but I'm stucked trying to use a dropdownlist button, the desing is show below
[image]

and the code is:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                                tabindex="-1">
                                            Select Option
                                        </button>

                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                                                data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                                        </button>

                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Option I</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option II</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option III</a></li>

                                            <li class="divider"></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option IV</a></li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textaux">

                                </div>
                            </div
```

what I want is that when the user select a value, the input type text control shows the value selected, in order to accomplish that, I have created this script

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
        var selText = $(this).text();
        $(this).parents('.form-group').find('#textaux').html(selText + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
    });
});
```

but it doesnt show any value, could you please help me and tell me how to modify the script in order to show in the text control the value selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it doesnt show any value, could you please help me and tell me how to modify the script in order to show in the text control the value selected

Instead of [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) (Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.) you can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) (For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.)  and instead of [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) you must use [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) in order to set the value of your input text box.

Moreover, an input text box cannot contain an html element:

```
<span class="caret"></span>
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
      var selText = $(this).text();
      $(this).closest('.form-group').find('#textaux').val(selText);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">

            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        tabindex="-1">
                    Select Option
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Option I</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option II</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option III</a></li>

                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option IV</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textaux">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```